# How to know if overlay is used on top of my android app?

Tags: android, overlay

Lets say I have an application `MyApp`. Is there a way for me to check if another app is using overlay on top of my application and then be like *Hey yo....no overlay of my app allowed!*

So far when I google `detect overlay in an app` I get tips on how to manually disable overlay over all or fix some overlay issues people have.

To clarify - I am not asking about checking if my app has permissions to draw over other apps...but for a way for my app to block other apps from using overlay over it... or if not block them then to be unusable until the overlay is turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views in the overlay are visual-only; they do not receive **input events and do not participate in focus traversal**. Overlay views are intended to be transient, such as might be needed by a temporary animation effect.

Due to this your app might never detect that there are Overlays on it until and unless it is generated from same parent.

[Google Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroupOverlay.html)

Comment: Despite acceptance by OP, the question is about [Overlays](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/design/overlays), which is a different feature than the one described by this answer. Definitely something user can interact with: currently a malware attack vector.

Comment: what is malware attack vector @ToolmakerSteve?